# function call only once then errors on function it just executed

Tags: jquery, function

I'm posting some data and retrieving it in a new menu. When I do this, I want to animate my button everytime (specifically rotate it). Rotation happens the first time, but stops executing the second time (my posts work). Firebug throws an error after the first function call that prevents the function from running again (im using jquery rotate plugin).

```
function submitlogic(){
if(pagetrack == 1){
    $.post('combine2.php',firstpost,function(data) { 
        $("#newmenu").html(data);                       
        });
    rotation(); // image rotates but gives firebug error: $("#gear").rotate is not a function
    pagetrack = 2;
} else if(pagetrack == 2){
    $.post('combine3.php',secondpost,function(data) { 
        $("#newmenu").html(data);
        });
    rotation(); // the error prevents this call from executing
    pagetrack = 3;
}

function rotation(){
   $("#gear").rotate({
     angle:0, 
     animateTo:-360,
     easing: $.easing.easeInOutExpo,
     callback: rotation
});
```

So my newbie questions are:

1. If its erroring, how is the function running the first time? The animation is doing exactly what it should do the first time. What's it getting hung up on?
2. What can i do to prevent this?

Comment: which plugin are you using?  make sure you are using it correctly.. for example does it handle -360?

Comment: and you sure you want to call it with itself as the callback function??

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples

im using the middle of example three

Comment: yea something is wrong with the callback, but if i remove it, the image doesnt rotate at all

Comment: i think i see the problem, my rotation calls in submitlogic isn't finding the rotation code underneath it. I dont know how to fix this though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, for anyone out there that ends up googling this -- i fixed this. There's nothing wrong with the code. But there is something wrong with the data being posted.

I was using some php from an old junk website thinking only the php calls would load. There was some commented out javascript at the top and the script tag recalling the jquery library. I stripped that, and i everything started working.

I guess the lesson here is, check to make sure you're calling what you intend to call. I guess the other stuff in the posted page alters how the original functions.